# Error while loading libraries

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

Content of my makefile:

```
all: compile launch

compile:
    g++ main.cpp -c -I/media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/include 

launch:
    g++ main.o -o result -L/media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/lib -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics
```

And when I'm trying launch program I get this:

```
./result: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-window.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Although my SFML paths are right and file **libsfml-window.so.2.4** exist

What I must change in Makefile to make it work?

PS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: double check your path, issue seems related with your path to SFML files

Comment: Please show `ls -l /media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-window*`

Besides that, as far as I understand you launch the program not from the Makefile, but from the command line you give by hands, right? Then I assume the Makefile has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @dmi ![valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/OQakv5J).

Comment: ![valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a4FpEfI) фев is february on rus

Comment: @Eidan, sorry I cannot understand your comment. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @dmi this is link to `ls -l /media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-window*` ( http://imgur.com/a4FpEfI ) and it's link to my process of launching ( http://imgur.com/OQakv5J  ) In dark blue window you can see my makefile and above you  can see path to my makefile

Comment: I cannot access that, please paste as text, or send in a message.

Comment: @dmi  first part of `ls -l /media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/lib/libsfml-windo‌​w*`  indent here   `lrwxrwxrwx 1 eidan eidan      23 фев 22 20:23 libsfml-window-d.so -> libsfml-window-d.so.2.4`    indent here   
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 eidan eidan      25 фев 22 20:23 libsfml-window-d.so.2.4 -> libsfml-window-d.so.2.4.2`   indent here   
`-rw-r--r-- 1 eidan eidan 1269880 фев 10 17:19 libsfml-window-d.so.2.4.2`
  indent here    `-rw-r--r-- 1 eidan eidan  322658 фев 10 17:21 libsfml-window-s.a`
`

Comment: That's what I assumed - I don't see a file named like libsfml-window.so or libsfml-window.so.XX.XX. What I see in your listing is I assume a debug version of the library with prefix -d. Perhaps you have somewhere else the libsfml-window.so which was used while linking but cannot be found while execution?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with one of following ways:
 1. Create /etc/ld.so.conf.d/some.conf file and add /media/eidan/soft/c++/Libraries/SFML-2.4.2/lib path there
 2. Create a launch script, exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH of your linked shared libraries dir upon start. This library path can be exported for any launched bash session manually.
-L CFLAG is being used only by the compiler. Library path is not being included to the final binary file.